# Number of subsets satisfying the additional condition

Tags: combinatorics

How to find the number of $m$-element subsets of the given $n$-element set such that every two different of these $m$-element subsets have precisely $k$ common elements?

Is there a formula for number of such subsets?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. You want the number of $m$-element subsets satisfying a condition that depends on more than one $m$-element subset.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: I wonder if you are looking for the generalization of [Erdős–Ko–Rado theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Ko%E2%80%93Rado_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Put any $k$ elements in each subset, and use the other elements to reach $m$, you'll create
$\frac{n-k}{m-k}$ subsets.

Still need to prove this is the maximum